# Disable Animation CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I animated `<span>` with 2 `@keyframe` function and I try to disable one of it when entering mobile view. How should I disable animation: moving? This is my code.

```
    /* Animate */
span {
    animation: 
    animate 5s linear infinite,
    moving 18s infinite;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0.70em;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%
    {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    100%
    {
        color: #B37A4C;
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #B37A4C;
    }
}

@keyframes moving {
    0%{margin-left: 100px;}
    10%{margin-left: 50px;}
    20%{margin-right: 100px;}
    30%{margin-right: 50px;}
    40%{margin-left: 100px;}
    50%{margin-left: 50px;}
    60%{margin-right: 100px;}
    70%{margin-right: 50px;}
    80%{margin-left: 100px;}
    90%{margin-left: 50px;}
    100%{margin-right: 100px;}
}
/* animate */












/* media queries  */

@media (max-width:1200px){

    html{
        font-size: 55%;
    }

    .home{
        padding:1rem 4rem;
    }

}

@media (max-width:991px){

header{
    left:-120%;
}

#menu{
    display: block;
}

header.toggle{
    left:0%;
}

body{
    padding:0;
}


}

@media (max-width:768px){

    html{
        font-size: 50%;
    }

}

@media (max-width:400px){

    header{
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .heading{
        margin:0 3rem;
    }

    .about .row .counter .box{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .education .box-container .box{
        width:100%;
    }

    .portfolio .box-container .box{
        width:100%;
    }

    .contact .row form{
        margin:3rem 0;
    }

    span .moving{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

How do I disable `@keyframe` moving in `@media (max-width:400px)`?

Comment: you can add media query like @media (max-width:460px){                                       
    span {
    animation: 
    animate 5s linear infinite, /// add only one that you want to apply
}}  // animate animation must be bellow this media query

Comment: It still animating 2 animation, because that code didn't disable the original code.

Answer (score 0):

After you have set the 2 animations for every span, set just the first one in your media query:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    span {animation: 
    animate 5s linear infinite;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0.70em;
  }
}
```

So your CSS becomes:

```
    /* Animate */
span {
    animation: 
    animate 5s linear infinite, moving 18s infinite;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0.70em;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    span {animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0.70em;
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%
    {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    100%
    {
        color: #B37A4C;
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #B37A4C;
    }
}

@keyframes moving {
    0%{margin-left: 100px;}
    10%{margin-left: 50px;}
    20%{margin-right: 100px;}
    30%{margin-right: 50px;}
    40%{margin-left: 100px;}
    50%{margin-left: 50px;}
    60%{margin-right: 100px;}
    70%{margin-right: 50px;}
    80%{margin-left: 100px;}
    90%{margin-left: 50px;}
    100%{margin-right: 100px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include a new animation declaration for that element ***after*** the other styles, it will only apply the one set, wrapped in media query or not.

```css
    /* Animate */
span {
    animation: 
    animate 5s linear infinite,
    moving 18s infinite;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0.70em;
    font-size:20px;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%
    {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    100%
    {
        color: #B37A4C;
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #B37A4C;
    }
}

@keyframes moving {
    0%{margin-left: 100px;}
    10%{margin-left: 50px;}
    20%{margin-right: 100px;}
    30%{margin-right: 50px;}
    40%{margin-left: 100px;}
    50%{margin-left: 50px;}
    60%{margin-right: 100px;}
    70%{margin-right: 50px;}
    80%{margin-left: 100px;}
    90%{margin-left: 50px;}
    100%{margin-right: 100px;}
}
/* animate */


span {
    animation:moving 18s infinite;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 0.70em;
}
```

```html
<span>span</span>
```